# openCL release GPU memory

Tags: c++, memory, opencl, gpu

I try to release allocated memory in GPU using OpenCL

```
int arraySize = 130000000;
cl_int* A = new cl_int[arraySize];
cl::Buffer gpuA(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(cl_int) * arraySize);
inA.setDestructorCallback(&notNeed);
cl::Event event;
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(gpuA, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_int) * arraySize, A, NULL, &event);
event.setCallback(CL_COMPLETE, &whenWritten);
event.wait();
```

and after a few sec callback whenWritten is running (writing text Complete)
program memory is incresing and using TaskManager in windows10 - GPU (Dedicated memory usage) I see in chart incresing memory level too.
Very Good ;-)

then i run sleep for 10s

and now I would like to clear memory in GPU
for local variable A I use

```
delete A; //local memory is decresing
```

but when I using

```
clReleaseMemObject(gpuA());
```

I don't see any changes on GPU memory

What I doing wrong ? What is the best solution for this ?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: `clReleaseMemObject(gpuA());` is incorrect for OpenCL C++ Bindings,  clReleaseMemObject is C API. cl::Buffer destructor will call to `clReleaseMemObject`

Answer (score 0):

OK so I replace buffer and clean buffer to C not C++

```
cl_mem gpuA2 = clCreateBuffer(context(), CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(cl_int) * arraySize, NULL, NULL);
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue(), gpuA2, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_int) * arraySize, A, 0, NULL, NULL);

queue.finish();
clReleaseMemObject(gpuA2);
delete A;
```

and after run I don't see any difference